# Orbeon 4.2 switch case

Tags: switch-statement, orbeon

I am trying to upgrade my orbeon to using the new **orbeon 4.2**. But I have a problem in the `switch case` that I used in my source code. It is having problem trying to **toggle** the case.

```
<xforms:action ev:event="xxforms-invalid" ev:observer="main">
            <xforms:toggle case="invalid-form-case" if="instance('main')/current_session/student_module_regn_status = 'Close'"/>
        </xforms:action>
        <xforms:action ev:event="xxforms-valid" ev:observer="main">
            <xforms:toggle case="valid-form-case" if="instance('main')/current_session/student_module_regn_status = 'Open'"/>
        </xforms:action>
```

Below is the code for the switch case :

```
<xforms:switch>
<xforms:case id="invalid-form-case">
    Closed
</xforms:case>
<xforms:case id="valid-form-case">
    Open
</xforms:case>
```

Thanks

Here is a example that would reproduce the problem :

```
    <html xmlns:xxforms="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/xforms"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xforms="http://www.w3.org/2002/xforms"
    xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events"
    xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"
    xmlns:xxi="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/xinclude"
    xmlns:widget="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/widget"
    xmlns:xdt="http://www.w3.org/2005/02/xpath-datatypes"
    xmlns:f="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/formatting"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <title>test</title>
    <xhtml:link rel="stylesheet" href="/apps/uis-common/css/app-form.css" type="text/css"/>
    <xforms:model>
        <xforms:instance id="main">
            <mains>
                <test1>Open</test1>
            </mains>
        </xforms:instance>

        <xforms:action ev:event="xxforms-invalid" ev:observer="main">
            <xforms:toggle case="invalid-form-case" if="instance('main')/test1 = 'Close'"/>
        </xforms:action>

        <xforms:action ev:event="xxforms-valid" ev:observer="main">
            <xforms:toggle case="valid-form-case" if="instance('main')/test1 = 'Open'"/>
        </xforms:action>
    </xforms:model>
</head>

<body dir="ltr">
    <div>
        <table width="100%" id="wrapper" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <xforms:switch>
                        <xforms:case id="invalid-form-case">
                            CLOSE
                        </xforms:case>
                        <xforms:case id="valid-form-case">
                            OPEN
                        </xforms:case>
                    </xforms:switch>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

it suppose to show "OPEN" as the "test1" is Open but no matter what the "test1" is, it just show "CLOSE"

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong in your code. Do you have a standalone example which would reproduce the issue?

Comment: i had add an example in my post above, i got the error when i using the orbeon 4.2.

Comment: I try changing the <xforms:action ev:event="xxforms-invalid" ev:observer="main"> to <xforms:action ev:event="xforms-ready"> and now it is working. could the problem cause by xxforms-invalid or the ev:observer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for the change is as follows:

In previous versions, the `xxforms-valid` and `xxforms-invalid` events dispatched to `xforms:instance` were dispatched during each revalidation. In recent versions, this behavior has changed, as [mentioned in the compatibility notes](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/release-notes/40#TOC-Behavior-of-extension-xxforms-valid-and-xxforms-invalid-events).

As per the XForms processing model, upon XForms initialization, the following is done:

- creation of models and instances
- initial recalculate and revalidate
- creation of the control tree

In your example, the first `xxforms-valid` or `xxforms-invalid` event is dispatched *before* the control tree is created. This means that your event handler doesn't find controls to toggle. Before 4.0, you would probably get at least one dispatch of `xxforms-valid` or `xxforms-invalid` *after* the control tree got created, so the toggle would work.

The better fix is probably to do something like this:

```
<xf:toggle
  ev:event="xforms-ready"
  if="xxf:valid(instance('main'), true())"
  case="...">
```